# jQuery .ajax .done not working with function

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me what outrageously simple mistake I have made here with `.done()` ?

why does:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: urlAction,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            parm1: value,
            parm2: value2
        }
    })
    .done(alert('done'));
```

Show me the alert, but

```
.done(function (data) { alert('done'); });
```

does not?

(The AJAX call goes off fine in both cases.)

Comment: this should also work. Its a standard way to handle response. are you getting any error in console?

Comment: nope, just no alert. (there is a warning "jquery.min.js:5 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." but I don't know if that's to do with my call or other code on the page.

Comment: Just like in the examples from [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/#deferred-done-doneCallbacks-doneCallbacks)!

Comment: Alexander, the docs were, of course, my very first port of call. As far as I can see, my code is exactly as the docs say it should be. I am asking if I have somehow misread or mistyped something!

Comment: for the record, ```.done(function ()
    {
        alert("$.ajax done");
    });```  also does not work.

Comment: `.done(function(data) {alert('done');}());` is working. But I don't undersend why don't work original syntax?

Comment: try using [`async: true`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) attribute on your `ajax` call (should default to true if not specified, but if you are getting a warning about synchronous requests?).. Additionally, where and what is `urlAction`? Does the request make it to the function?

Comment: Alexander, yes, that last does work - but that is NOT what is in the docs - or at least not the parts I have seen? Can you maybe point me to where this is explained?

Comment: Sandman, that does not clear the warning, must be other page code.

Comment: @kpollock, I'm sorry, but I so confused as you!

Comment: Alexander - I don't understand why the original isn't working either!! But your answer works, Thanks!! Put it as an answer and I'll make that the accepted answer.

Comment: @kpollock, I doubt what it's right. Maybe the executing of this expression will be independed on ajax resolving (same as Immediately-Invoked Function Expression).